# Error while connecting mongodb whit moongose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I run my project in TypeScript with Node.js and its showing me this error:

[image: 1]

part 2:

[image: 2]

My code screenshots:

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: which ```mongoose``` version are you using? is it latest?

Comment: Please make sure your mongodb instance is up and running. Also please improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config.ts` try changing PORT to 5000 or any other except `27017`, I guess you are trying to run your server on PORT 27017 which is the default PORT for mongodb server.

Make sure that your mongodb server is up and running, you can use `Robo3t` or `MongoDB Compass` if you are new to mongodb. These tools provide you with an easy GUI interface to interact with your database.

*Suggestion: Try providing code snippets rather than screenshot links.*